# Environment variables from /etc/environment not propagated to child process?

Tags: 10.10, environment-variables, process

I'm having a problem. I have set an environment variable in `/etc/environment` using `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR="/usr/local/lib/boost/release"`.

`echo $BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` correctly echoes the value to the terminal. However, if I execute `echo $BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` in a script using `./test.sh` it shows the env variable as empty. As I understand it, it should be set also for child processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an environment variable to be passed to children you must export it.  To verify if it is exported use the `env` command.  The safest way to do this is as follows.

```
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR="/usr/local/lib/boost/release"; export BOOST_LIBRARYDIR
```

Newer shells like `bash` and `ksh` accept the simpler form.

```
export BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ="/usr/local/lib/boost/release"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `/etc/environment` seems to be sourced from `/etc/init/gdm.conf`, I think you can substitute your line with

```
export BOOST_LIBRARYDIR="/usr/local/lib/boost/release"
```